# Problems with loop in R

Tags: r

```
mom.wealth <- matrix(NA,nrow(dax.p),1)

mom.wealth[13,1]=1

mom.stocks <- matrix(NA,nrow(dax.p),ncol(dax.p))

for (row in 13:nrow(dax.p)-1) {
   for (column in 2:ncol(dax.p)) {
     mom.stocks[row,column] <- mom.wealth[row,1]*mom.weight[row,column]/dax.p[row,column]
  }

   mom.wealth[row+1,1] <- sum(mom.stocks[row,-1]*dax.p[row+1,-1])
}
```

There is something wrong with the last line here. It does not come any error message, but all results are just NA.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The `RStudio` tag is for questions that involve the RStudio IDE per se, not general R questions (which is what this is). Also -- you really should post enough data for someone to be able to reproduce your problem. Please read [mcve].

Comment: Second the request for sample data. Specifically, we don't know what `mom.wealth` or `dax.p` *look like*. Another quick reference for asking a *reproducible question* (very important to get a relevant answer) is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root-case of the problem is `for (row in 13:nrow(dax.p)-1)` line.

You can try this simple code to understand the problem.

```
for (row in 13:16-1) {
  print(row) 
}

The above code will print like
[1] 12
[1] 13
[1] 14
[1] 15
```

That means 1 is subtracted from both 13 and 16 before checking fro `in` condition.

Now, in your case the actual value is at `13th` row of `mom.wealth` but your loop starts from 12th row. The 12th row has `NA` value. Hence, subsequent rows will get `NA`.

The fix is: Change the line `for (row in 13:nrow(dax.p)-1)` 
with
`for (row in 13:(nrow(dax.p)-1))`

Comment: That was the problem! I'm so grateful. Thank you very much!

Comment: @R_learner Happy to help. You can accept the answer by clicking tick in left of answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
mom.wealth <- matrix(NA,nrow(dax.p),1)

mom.wealth[13,1]=1

mom.stocks <- matrix(NA,nrow(dax.p),ncol(dax.p))

for (row in 13:nrow(dax.p)-1) {


for (column in 2:ncol(dax.p)) {


mom.stocks[row,column] <- mom.wealth[row,1]*mom.weight[row,column]/dax.p[row,column] }

mom.wealth[row+1,1] <- sum(mom.stocks[row,-1]*dax.p[row+1,-1], na.rm = T) }
```

If it does not work  I need dataset to understand the problem...